# How to get difference between two dates and time?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, datetime

I am working on Quiz App. In my app I want to get difference between quiz start time and end time. How to get difference between start and end time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google could have found you answer in no time! you wasted time posting a question here.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The `NSDate` class has a method `timeIntervalSinceDate` that does the trick.

```
NSTimeInterval interval = [firstDate timeIntervalSinceDate:secondDate];
```

Comment: A day is not the same amount of seconds in every calendar.

Comment: @GianlucaTranchedone can u please post some link for your comment

Comment: You should specify it, then.

Comment: @GianlucaTranchedone what you mean to say, a day can have variable number of seconds.

Comment: Although the Gregorian calendar is the most used in the world, it's not the only one. Other popular calendars are the Buddhist and Japanese calendars. Moreover http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day, look at the bottom. About the link, here you are https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html

Comment: @GianlucaTranchedone Just give a reference of any section from your ref doc where it is specify that a day can have a variable number of seconds.

Comment: I've just edited my previous comment.

Comment: BTW, to know exactly how many days have elapsed between two dates, you should use NSDateComponents and NSCalendar. This classes provide the right tools for the job. You will always get the right result, no matter what.

Comment: Read first line from the link shared by you, "A day is a unit of time. In common usage, it is an interval equal to 24 hours". I think no reason for downvote :(

Comment: @ikegami I had updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **NSDate** `- (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSinceDate:(NSDate *)anotherDate` for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy"];
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy"];
    NSString *dateString11 = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
    NSDate *today1 = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:dateString11];
    NSDate *ExpDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"ExpDate"];
    NSTimeInterval interval = [ExpDate timeIntervalSinceDate:today1];
    int diff=interval/86400;
```

i hope this code useful for you.

And Another code for you.

```
 NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSDate *ServerDate = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:@"04/26/2013"];
[dateFormatter1 release];
NSTimeInterval interval = [date timeIntervalSinceDate:ServerDate];
int diff=interval/86400;
NSLog(@"%d",diff);
```

Comment: Some days have 22, 23, 24, 25 or 26 hours due to changes in and out of daylight savings time. `86400` is wrong.

Comment: This is for 60 days check code so you add your date minutes .24*60*60=86400.You use this type of calculation

Comment: It could report 59 or 61 days when it's 60 with your buggy code.

Comment: In my code that code is perfect work .and i can get 60 days in nslog of diff.

Comment: Please check Again.Thanks

Comment: Yes, and you can also get 59 or 61

Comment: in one by one month date is 31 or 30 days so you get 61 days. i also check and get 31 days.

Comment: If you got 31 or 61 days and you were expecting 31 or 61 days, then your didn't use the right dates and times in your test. Again, it's possible to be off by one.